# Maintain different workflows for different domains in same android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am developing a single app for different domains. When an application is started and once I get the domain type I need to maintain the single workflow for the particular domain.Based on the domain type selected the flow will work. I have one solution available one is to save Domain type in `SharedPreference` and checking every time the domain from preference and set labels on `Fragments` and `Activity` reusing the Fragments etc and performing actions accordingly. But the problem here is always checking using `if...else` conditions for all domain type and performing actions accordingly. How to resolve this?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/inheritance.html

Comment: What do you mean with "domains"? Something like "demo version, paid version, free version" of the same app? In that case, probably you need a product flavor: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: Domain in my  case you can say Business type (School,College  etc)